# ASP.NET Web Api - error while trying to list all objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

my Web API consists of 3 classes: CustomTask, Payment and Client.

CustomTask has reference (belongs) to Client.

Payment has reference to CustomTask.

I have added test Client, and everything was fine. But when I have added CustomTask associated to this Client I got error while listing it in my web browser:

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace/>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.CustomTask_C8E7E37C41E5E531B4F79887952391B7F9896801C32E9876AA3C63332F3B5A9A' with data contract name 'CustomTask_C8E7E37C41E5E531B4F79887952391B7F9896801C32E9876AA3C63332F3B5A9A:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) at WriteArrayOfCustomTaskToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract ) at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteObject(XmlWriter writer, Object graph) at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content) at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__1b.MoveNext()
</StackTrace>
</InnerException>
</Error>
```

How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

CustomTask.cs

```
public class CustomTask
{
    public CustomTask() { }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Client")]
    [Required]
    public int ClientID { get; set; }

    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Technology { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long EstimatedTime { get; set; }

    public long RealTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    [Required]
    public bool Finished { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    [Required]
    public bool Lessons { get; set; }

    public string ArchiveID { get; set; }
}
```

Client.cs:

```
public class Client
{
    public Client() { }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Names { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string Info { get; set; }
}
```

My `ClientsController` and `CustomTasksController` are generated by Visual Studio.

`ClientsController` returns beautiful XML, which is also serialized with no problems using Client app written using WinForms:

```
<ArrayOfClient xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/...">
<Client>
<Address/>
<Email/>
<ID>1</ID>
<Info/>
<Names>saddasdasd</Names>
<Phone/>
</Client>
<Client>
<Address/>
<Email/>
<ID>2</ID>
<Info/>
<Names>saddasdasd</Names>
<Phone/>
</Client>
</ArrayOfClient>
```

**EDIT:**
I have just discovered, that the problem only occurs when my Web API is deployed in Azure, locally everything works fine.

**EDIT:**
I found an answer, solution is adding `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` to connection string while deploying to Azure.

Comment: Two words: `View Models`. Those two magical words will solve your problem.

Comment: There is a concept, an error, but no code that produces that error, no models, etc. The question is not clear

Comment: Please update the question with your code so that we can see what is wrong.

Comment: Looks like it can't serialize XML, do you even want XML? I think you are looking for JSON. I this case add `Accept: aplication/json` in request headers.
Or change config: add this two lines inside `WebApiConfig.Rgister(...)`: `config.Formatters.Clear();
config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());`

Comment: Thanks guys, I have updated my post with models

Comment: After changing formatting to JSON now I got this error:
`{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Error getting value from 'Client' on 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.CustomTask_C8E7E37C41E5E531B4F79887952391B7F9896801C32E9876AA3C63332F3B5A9A'`